# Order by date and auto increment column (id), but order rows with same value for third column (oid) alphabetically by fourth column (ab)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Following Quassnoi's answer I have edited to show what happens using his advice and added letters to the OID to show the problematic ordering.

I have a table in a mysql database that I first want to order by the date it was supposed to be added to the database.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_placed DESC;
```

Next where the date is the same I want to order by an auto incremented id. So I've added:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_placed DESC, id DESC;
```

I end up with something like this:

```
Date_Placed |  ID  |  OID   |  AB
05/01/2012  | 1100 |  A50   |  A
05/01/2012  | 1109 |  A50   |  B
05/01/2012  | 1108 |  B40   |  A
05/01/2012  | 1107 |  B40   |  B
04/01/2012  | 1106 |  C30   |  A
04/01/2012  | 1105 |  C30   |  B
```

The AB field will always only by A or B, and OID may either exist twice or be a unique value.
What I want now is in those cases where OID is duplicated, for B to come before A in the AB column. Note that ID will then be out of order to an extent.

```
Date_Placed |  ID  |  OID   |  AB
05/01/2012  | 1109 |  A50   |  B
05/01/2012  | 1110 |  A50   |  A
05/01/2012  | 1107 |  B40   |  B
05/01/2012  | 1108 |  B40   |  A
04/01/2012  | 1105 |  C30   |  B
04/01/2012  | 1106 |  C30   |  A
```

I'd prefer to do this on the mysql side since I'll be retrieving quite a few rows. Is this possible? If not in mysql then I am using php so what would be the best way to do it in that? Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Quassnoi's answer gives this:

```
Date_Placed |  ID  |  OID   |  AB
05/01/2012  | 1107 |  B40   |  B
05/01/2012  | 1108 |  B40   |  A
05/01/2012  | 1109 |  A50   |  B
05/01/2012  | 1110 |  A50   |  A
04/01/2012  | 1105 |  C30   |  B
04/01/2012  | 1106 |  C30   |  A
```

ID order is lost

Comment: If you had these rows: `(1110, B50); (1107, B50); (1108; A40); (1109; A40)`, what would the order be?

Comment: @Quassnoi This wouldn't happen since if two rows share an OID it means they were added one after the other, meaning their IDs will be incremental.

Comment: Are all your values inserted by a single connection in a single thread? If not, this cannot be relied upon because two insert operations can get out of order (with `InnoDB`, even if batched).

Comment: Yes they are both added at the same time in a single insert statement with some php tweaking to obtain the different values for AB and a few other fields not mentioned. But AB will always be different if two rows have the same OID.

Comment: does `B` always go before `A` in `id` order?

Comment: yes B will always be before A

Comment: and there can be only `A`, only `B` or `A, B` in a single `oid`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  date_placed, oid, MAX(id) AS mid
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                date_placed, oid
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      (m.date_placed, m.oid) = (md.date_placed, md.oid)
ORDER BY
        m.date_placed DESC, mid DESC, ab DESC
```

If two conditions hold:

1. `id` within a single `oid` are consecutive (no gaps between them), and
2. `B` always goes before `A` in `id` order,

use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        date_placed DESC,
        CASE ab WHEN 'A' THEN id - 1 ELSE id END DESC,
        id
```

, without joins.

Comment: Gives me the right order for AB but the ID order is completely lost and gives the same results whether it is in the statement or not.

Comment: @mrmryb: of course, since the first three columns are unique. But this produces the resultset you've posted. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I have edited the post to expand on the issue. Apologies for not making it clearer first time round.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure it out with it being so ridiculously complicated. This is working though so thank you very much.

Comment: Wow that is a much friendlier looking solution and works perfect too, thank you twice.